# Normal vector in discrete 3D object

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, graphics3d

Consider a large array(~42000,3):

```
array={{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},...,{xn,yn,zn}};
```

This array forms a certain shape, it may contain cavities or other discontinuities. It can be translated periodically and some of these features can be removed from the area we are considering. Ideally I would like to used the discrete data and create a a function F[x,y,z] such that I can just take the gradient and obtain the normal vector as a function of x,y,z , but I dont think it is possible.

Therefore I need a way to do a discrete gradient. It would be good enough to be able to get every 3 nearby points make a plane and get the direction of the plane respect to the z axis, along with the coordinate. I have tried to make a ConvexHull and go from there but that only works in very simple shapes. Any thoughts or ideas will be appreciated? 
The link contains a .csv file of the data.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ABNqdgGdmYek8TwGby3sPGKjcB2IrYuo?usp=sharing
[image: Image of the surface Im trying to work with.]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a very hard problem. You may use `ListSurfacePlot3D` with a sufficiently high setting of `MaxPlotPoints` (about 250) in order to get an impression of (some components) of the surface. But as you will see that won't return a completely satisfactory surface, let alone good surface normals. The point cloud seems to be sampled from some analytic data, though. Are you sure that you don't have access to some mesh combinatorics for it?